# Can desmume connect to wireless to trade pokemon with yourself?

Tags: emulation, pokemon-fifth-generation, desmume

I'm trying to trade Pokemon between Black and White on Desmume Wifi-capable. For some reason I cannot get the emulator to connect to a network so I can use the global trading or any of the wireless features in the games.

I've followed video tutorials but the emulator still won't connect. What steps are needed to get a connection so that I can trade between the two games?

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to trade between two instances of emulator or emulator and the handheld?
You can try https://www.pokecheck.org/ or if you google around, it's possible to find a downloadable GTS emulator (it's called fakeGTS), but I'm not sure if it's allowed to link to it here.

Comment: trying to do emulator to emulator.  a few videos show using a virtual windows that makes the game think its connected directly.  right now I only have desmume as the ds emulator and wasn't sure if I needed to different emulators.

Comment: I have never done that, so I wouldn't know, but I know you can use fakeGTS (and probably pokecheck, since it's running a version of fakeGTS) with an emulator, both to send and to receive pokemon.

Comment: I'm trying that pokecheck, but my issue is that the emulator can't connect to the wifi.  I get an error code 52000 unable to connect, or 52100 unable to connect.  Searching for an access point only find "softap".  How do I get it to actually connect to the network?

Comment: From what I remember, wifi is disabled in mainstream builds and you need to either compile it yourself or find a precompiled executable that is guaranteed to work. I can't help you with that, because I haven't used an emulator in few years, but if you search the desmume forums you should be able to find something about it.

Comment: I've got my desmume to connect to Nintendo wifi, but im having trouble with the global trade in pokemon black/white.  I want to trade a houndour from black for a purloin from white so I put up houndour as an offer and put purloin as the wanted, when going to global trade in the white version, I go to complete the trade but it won't let me search for houndour because the GHI block is unusable.  Why is this?

Comment: You can't connect emulator to official GTS, they have a whitelist of wifi adapters that only their handhelds use. There are other, non-official GTS' available which you should be able to use.

Comment: Also, if I'm not mistaken, Nintendo is closing NinWFC services for DS games on May 20th of this year. :c

Comment: Pokecheck is down. Any alternatives?

Comment: @CanadianLuke Look up where to download fakeGTS, it's what pokecheck uses as their base. Or you can wait for pokecheck to stop having a maintenance...